# Как начать функцию заново, если она выдаст ошибку?

Tags: python

У меня есть функция и в любом месте может произойти ошибка. Как я могу начать ее заново, если ее выполнение закончится ошибкой? Работает ли try, except прямо на вызов функции?

Comment: _"Работает ли try, except прямо на вызов функции?"_, — работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
while True:
    try:
        f()
        break
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Гениально! Спасибо